# JavaScript create object merging array and a Dict

Tags: javascript

I have a reference dict:

```
  a = [
    { name: 'a'},
    { name: 'b'},
    { name: 'c'}
  ];
```

and a second array called (received via a API as a response)

```
data = [10,20,30]
```

I want to join the Dict and the array together and make something like:

Output:

```
[{
'a': 10,
'b': 20,
'c':30
}]
```

i tried foreach() though 'data' and pass the index to Dict 'a' obtain the key and do a push() for a new Dict but seems like foreach() exiting prematurely.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem. If `a` has at least the same number of elements the described way shouldn't _"exit prematurely"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```js
var initial = performance.now();

var a = [
  { name: 'a' },
  { name: 'b' },
  { name: 'c' }
];

var data = [10, 20, 30];
var finalObject = {};
a.forEach((item, index) => finalObject[item.name] = data[index]);
var result = [finalObject];

console.log(result);
var final = performance.now();
console.log(`Time taken to run: ${final - initial}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) `a` and take advantage of the index in the callback to create your merged object:

```js
var initial = performance.now();

var a = [
  {name: 'a'},
  {name: 'b'},
  {name: 'c'}
];
var data = [10, 20, 30];

var output = [a.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
  acc[x.name] = data[i]
  return acc;
}, {})];

console.log(output);
var final = performance.now();
console.log(`Time taken to run: ${final-initial}`);
```